# How do you use selectors in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a couple of select elements on my page and want to get a list of the values of all the selected on the page with a certain class

```
<select class="selectedCam" @change="dosomething" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>select from below</option>
    <option value="1">Direction 1</option>
    <option value="2">Direction 2</option>
   ....
</select >
```

If a value is chosen from one select in my element I want to disable it in all the other selects in my element that share the same class. This list will be dynamic based on how many cams are plugged into my system at the time so I won't know how many are generated at any point in time.

I know I should not manipulate the Dom with JQuery when using vuejs.

But I know with JQuery I could look for `$('. selectedCam')` and get an array of objects that shared this class and find the current values for these elements that I could use on my onChange event to disable these options in the other selects once chosen.

Is there something similar in Vue Js?
Or should I try a different approach in Vue Js to disable these options in the other selects that get generated on the page?

Comment: Is the number of `<select>` you'll have fixed? With Vue, the DOM is rendered based on the state, and you can maintain a list of all cameras, and create a filtered list for each one of the dropdowns, based on the list and the selected items in other dropdowns. Then use that list to loop and create the `<option>` for each.

Answer (score 0):

To disable a selected value from a `select` tag in Vue, my approach would be this:

template

```
        <select class="selectedCam" @change="dosomething" v-model='selectedCam1'>
            <option value="" disabled selected>select from below</option>
            <option value="1" :disabled="selectedCam2 == 'Direction 1' || selectedCam3 == 'Direction 1'">Direction 1</option>
            <option value="2">Direction 2</option>
           ....
        </select >
        <select class="selectedCam" @change="dosomething" v-model='selectedCam2'>
            <option value="" disabled selected>select from below</option>
            <option value="1">Direction 1</option>
            <option value="2">Direction 2</option>
           ....
        </select >
  <select class="selectedCam" @change="dosomething" v-model='selectedCam3'>
            <option value="" disabled selected>select from below</option>
            <option value="1">Direction 1</option>
            <option value="2">Direction 2</option>
           ....
        </select >
```

data

```
data () {
   return {
      selectedCam1: '',
      selectedCam2: '',
      selectedCam3: '',
      ...
   }
}
```

So, here you can see I set option 1 from the first select to disable if select 2 or 3 is already set to `Direction 1`.

Comment: This would be great if I knew how many cams are present when I write the code but I don't know how many cams would be present anywhere from 1 to 16 cams.

Comment: Ahh I see, then yea there's definitely a better way than hardcoding 16 optional instances haha

Answer (score 0):

Disable selected values with v-if. See working example [on codepen](https://codepen.io/spigel-jack/pen/agzzgy)

**Example**

```
<div id="vue">
  <div class="input-select">
    <label>Country</label>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="selected.active = false">
      <option v-for="country in countries" v-bind:value="country" :key="country.name" v-if="country.active">
        {{ country.name }}
      </option>
    </select>

        <label>Country2</label>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="selected.active = false">
      <option v-for="country in countries" v-bind:value="country" :key="country.name" v-if="country.active">
        {{ country.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <h2>Selected: <strong>{{ selected }} ({{ selectedName }})</strong></h2>
</div>
```

**Updated**

```
<div id="vue">
  <div class="input-select">
    <label>Country</label>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="setHidden()">
      <option v-for="country in countries" v-bind:value="country" :key="country.name" :disabled="!country.active">
        {{ country.name }}
      </option>
    </select>

        <label>Country2</label>
    <select v-model="selected2">
      <option v-for="country in countries" v-bind:value="country" :key="country.name" v-if="country.active">
        {{ country.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <h2>Selected: <strong>{{ selected.name }}</strong>
    <h2>Selected2: <strong>{{ selected2.name }}</strong>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: this one here has some issues as well.  I tried the codepen and if I choose any option it removes it from the dropdowns, but it doesn't show in the <h2> as one of the two selected and it doesn't put the option back into the selects if I choose a different option in the selects.